# serialize and post array to a process file

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to post an array to another file to be processed. The array is below and it populates rows properly. I have it initialized at the beginning of the script tag to make it global.
 In javascript:

```
var locationsall = new Array();
locationsall[counter] = new Array();
locationsall[counter][0] = address;
locationsall[counter][1] = lat;
locationsall[counter][2] = lng;
```

In my form i try to serialzie it and post it

```
 <input type="hidden" name="result" value="<?php echo serialize($locationsall); ?>">
```

When i try to unserialize it, it doesn't have anything..

```
    $locations = unserialize($_POST['result']);
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What appears in the value attribute of the input element?

Comment: When i check page source is shows as value="N;" ... not sure what that means

Comment: The value is NULL. Can you show more of the form?

Comment: What is supposed to be changing the value of document.form.result ?

Comment: Clicking the second radio button and adding an address initiates the codeAddress() method which populates the locationsall array

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19245/discussion-between-cez-and-den)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are updating client-side data via jQuery, you need to set the value of result to whatever it is that you want to pass through. You can serialize a JS object using [jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/), so you can then pass through JSON-encoded data to PHP. When processing the post data you would then need to [decode the JSON data](http://uk.php.net/manual/ro/function.json-decode.php) in `$_POST['result']`

JS

```
var test = new Array('a', 'b');
var data = $.param(test);
$('#result').val(data);
...
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['result'])) {
    $data = (array) json_decode($_POST['result']);
}
```